# How do I repeat serial numbers from 000 to 999 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate serial numbers from 000 to 999 in Python and save them to a txt file

```
import os
os.system ('clear')

lis9 = 01000
while lis9 < 01099 :
   lis9 = lis9+1
   print (lis9)
```

How do I start from a specific number and end at a specific number?
The numbers start from zero

Each number begins on a new line

For example

```
01000
01001
.
01010
.
.
01099
```

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: share the code and we will see how we can help you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no code and no effort to find duplicates

Comment: I'm a newbie in Python, I don't know how to code and I want to learn

Comment: @mom You can start with beginner tutorials on YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f` string

```
with open('out.txt','w') as f:
    for n in range(0,1000):
        f.write(f'{n:03}\n')
```

output (*'out.txt'*)

```
000
001
002
003
...
996
997
998
999
```

Comment: Yes, this is. I don't want to do this

'0100
0101
.
0110
.
.
9999'

Comment: How do I start from a specific number and end at a specific number?

Comment: "How do I start from a specific number and end at a specific number? " --> `for n in range(start,stop)`

Comment: Tried this `for n in range(01000,01099):` and it didn't work

Comment: can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I like one liners for this kind of thing myself:

```
print([str(x)[-3:] for x in range(1000,2000)], sep="\n", file=open("out.txt","w"))
```

Answer (score -1):

The function `range()` can serve your goal:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

You can use it by `range(1000)` and then going through it by:

```py
for i in range(1000):
    print(i)
```

And it would print line by line from 0 to 999.
If you want the number to be 000 and not 0, (086 instead of 86 etc) you can use `print(f"{i:0>3}")`

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines("\n".join([f"{x:03}" for x in range(1000)]))
```